# How can I make an alert pop up that ask "are you sure you want to cancel?"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, I have this jQuery code for my cancel button

```
$('#cancel').click(function () {
    $('#edit').show();
    $('#savechanges, #cancel').hide();
    $("#target :input").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

How can I make an alert pop up if I click the cancel button? I know this is simple but I just want to learn.

Comment: Please add HTML code and better describe what button are we talking about. As for now, it's a candidate to be closed as off-topic -> needs more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `confirm` alert to make sure the user confirms their action before proceeding with the code you want for the cancel event.

```js
$('#cancel').click(function() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    $('#edit').show();
    $('#savechanges, #cancel').hide();
    $("#target :input").prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="cancel">cancel</button>
<button id="savechanges">Save</button>
<div id="edit">edit</div>
```

Comment: @ErfamaeFermo Glad to help you. Please tick mark the answer if that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `confirm` API:

```
if(confirm("Are you sure?"))
{
    //Ok button pressed...
}
else
{
    //Cancel button pressed...
}
```

Docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

"OK" and "Cancel" button can't be change text to Yes/No or anything else that works cross-browser. If you want that, you can find a jquery plugin for custom create a dialog for your own.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples for different types of prompts

```js
$(function() {

  $("[data-confirm]").on("click", function(){
      return confirm($(this).data("confirm"));
  });

  $("[data-alert]").on("click", function(){
      return alert($(this).data("alert"));
  });

  $("[data-prompt]").on("click", function(){
      return prompt($(this).data("prompt"));
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-confirm="Confirm!">Window.confirm()</button>
<button data-alert="Alert!">Window.alert()</button>
<button data-prompt="Prompt!">Window.prompt()</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way could be the simple `window.confirm('...')` solution.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Answer (score 0):

use `alert('Are you sure you want to delete')` for this. Or maybe you want to use confirm('press ok to confirm').

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var txt;
      var r = confirm("Press a button!");
  //alert("Hello\nHow are you?");

      if (r == true) {
        txt = "You pressed OK!";
//write you own functionality here.

      } else {
        txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
      }

    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sweet alert that isnt look like stone age style

```js
$('button').click(function(){

Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  icon: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal.fire(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
  }
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9.7.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js" integrity="sha256-1pZ3aajcQuFEOG/veUw/WxQjAMJiCSTZo8wH+opDplY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button>Popup</button>
```